# Что такое top-level position в HTML?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В  документации  **Bootstrap 4.1**  в ***разделе* Modal**  непонятное обозначение
 ***HTML top-level positions*** [ссылка](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/).

Какие  позиции являются top-level ?

Есть ли какая то общепринятая классификация HTML позиций ?

Comment: просто предположу, что, вероятно, разговор идет про z-индекс

Answer (score 6):

Они имели ввиду свойство `z-index` которое *должно* отвечать за позиционирование элемента по оси Z (ближе к пользователю или дальше), что бы его не перекрывали другие элементы.
(На данный момент это свойство равно `$zindex-modal: 1050 !default;`)